# How to resize the widget's size that are in QFileDialog?

Tags: qt, qt5, qfiledialog

I have tried

```
this->setStyleSheet ("QPushButton{min-height: 40px; min-width: 200px;}");
```

but this didn't work.

[image]

strong text

Answer (score 0):

From the image you show I can deduce that you want to set the size of the buttons shown in that same image, and those buttons are QToolButtons but you use QPushButton generating the error. The solution is to use:

```css
QFileDialog QToolButton{min-height: 40px; min-width: 200px;}
```

If you also want to resize the QPushButtons then you must use QAbstractButton:

```css
QFileDialog QAbstractButton{min-height: 40px; min-width: 200px;}
```

Comment: @bugfree provide a [mre]